# Merge NetworkSecurityConfig xml files in Manifest

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

In my application I set a network security configuration file with the following:

```
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

I'm setting in my manifest this way:

```
  <application 
             (...)
              android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Additionally, I'm adding a 3rd party lib which supplies its own network security config file with a set of domains

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">domainA</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Which they are setting in my manifest this way:

```
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

The problem is that the manifest merge only works in manifest.xml file (afaik), therefore the netowrk-security-config file will always be the application file and not the merge between the app and 3rd party network-security-config files, is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">domainA</domain>
    </domain-config>
     <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism to merge resources that way. You would need to have the combined network security configuration file in your app module, where you manually merge what you need and what the library requests.

Comment: I ended using what you suggested (creating a combined file) but only applied for debug APKs, since in my case, I only need this merge to happen in debug builds. Thank you

Comment: @commonsware  When I did this, I am getting the error `TrustKit was initialized with a different network policy than the one configured in the App's manifest.`

Comment: @Prashant: You would need to ask the developers of [TrustKit-Android](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android), whose library you appear to be using.